# Button visibility upon a click in html and php

Tags: php, html

I have a edit button that I would like it to be hidden before a user press on the insert button.

For example,

Firstly, I will click on .
Edit button of this code .
The add button will run the below php code.

```
            <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['img']))
        {

        $filename=  $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
        if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/png")  || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))&& ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 999999))
        {
        if(file_exists($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]))
        {
        echo "File name exists.";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "tmp_name=".$_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"];
        echo "destination="."images/$filename";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"/usr/local/apache/htdocs/Kxclusive/images/$filename");
        echo "Upload Successful . <a href='images/$filename'>Click here</a> to view the uploaded image";

        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "invalid file.";
        }
        }

        ?>
```

I would like the edit button to be visible after running the last line of the code in the php tag.

How should I do it?

Comment: I think you need to provide your javascript - clicking a button is a client-side action which doesn't directly trigger PHP (except a "form submit" button which would redraw an entire page/iframe). So... If you're calling this by AJAX, you need to do something on success. If you're doing it on form submit, you need to output either additional HTML for the enw button or a JS Script to show a hidden button.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to render any insert button. Also, reading code like what you have written is extremely hard because it hasn't been indented properly. Take a look as this instruction: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lT8N85DRzZQ

Answer (score 0):

You must check the status of the file first(whether it is uploaded or not) , then you can decide the visibility of the edit button
 according to that value for example

```
$status = codeforImageUploadChecking();
if($status==true){
        Edit  Button Code here
}
```